# Knockout mapping for objects in an array whose property name is dynamic

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a service that returns data of the following form (I can add fields to this, but I can't change the hierarchical structure):

```
{
    Sections: {
        3a: [
            {   
                /* Item definition */
                ID: 1,
                Text: "Completed Form INNSAMEM002",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ],
        3b: [
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to use the mapping plugin to call a custom constructor for each of the item definitions, but am having trouble because it is split into sections; so, a mapping would work like this:

```
var _mapping = {
    '3a': {
        create: function(o) { return new ItemModel(o.data); }
    }
});
```

However, the section names cannot be known ahead of time.

I can go through the AJAX data, find all the sections, and generate the mapping config from that before I run it, but just wanted to know if there is a better way?

SOLUTION: The answer from CrimsonChris gave me the way to do it; final mapping is this:

```
var _mapping =  {
    'Sections': {
        create: 
            function(o) 
            { 
                var res = {};

                $.each(o.data,
                    function(sectionkey, section)
                    {
                        var secres = [];

                        $.each(section,
                            function(itemindex, item) 
                            {
                                secres.push(new ItemModel(item));
                            }
                        );

                        res[sectionkey] = secres;
                    }
                );

                return res;
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: You could loop over the properties of `Sections` to get each section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the properties of `Sections` in the response to get each section. Then map each section's items to an `ItemModel`.

```
var _mapping = {
    'Sections': {
        create: function (options) {
            var sections = [];
            for (var sectionName in options.data) {
                sections.push(new SectionModel(options.data[sectionName], sectionName);
            }
            return sections;
        }
    }
}

function SectionModel(items, sectionName) {
    this.items = items.map((item) => new ItemModel(item));
    this.sectionName = sectionName;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax seems a bit off here - the mapping needs to be an object with 'Sections' as a key, and THEN the object containing the create function presumably? Nevertheless, this pointed me the right way, of creating a nested loop within the Sections create, so I'm marking it the answer! Thanks!